# web essentials 2012 crashes when I open a project that already has a file open

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-essentials

An interesting things is happening and I was hoping someone would be able to help me with it.

Visual Studio 2012 with Web Essentials installed was working fine until the latest update (the one where they removed less, coffeescript, etc.)

However since the update, I am having problems. This only happens when I open a project that has a file - which web essentials would act upon - already open.

If I close all of the tabs with cshtml/less/css files before I close a project. Then the next time I open that project, I am fine. I can even open those files, and web essentials kicks in with all of its extra features. But if even one of those files are open when the project was saved, and therefore opened automatically when the project is loaded, then the entire visual studio crashes.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Someone ask the same question a few days back. Think it is an issue with Web Essentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue after days and days of searching (only minutes after posting this question :))

The latest version of Web Essentials requires ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2
I had heard a lot about these Tools 2012.2 but I thought that they were an extension - maybe the "Microsoft Web Development Tools" installed automatically with visual studio or something that would get upgraded automatically with all of the auto updating software running on my machine.

So I tried updating all of the extensions and refreshing and refreshing and searching for updates - to no avail.

I even downloaded and installed VS2012 Update 2 CTP4 thinking that that must be this elusive update that everyone is talking about.

Well as I'm sure you guessed, its actually none of the above.
The link is http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282650

It is listed on the home page of web essentials but not on the page that pops up when you run the update.

I hope this link helps someone.